# Activate a Javascript function with a keypress

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

```
    function addone()
    {
            document.getElementById("subtract").disabled=false;
    x += 1;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Doshi has said OK " + x + " times."
if(x == 1 ){
    document.getElementById("resetall").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("reset").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Doshi has said OK " + x + " time."
}
if(x == 0){
    document.getElementById("resetall").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("reset").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Doshi has not said OK "
}
    }
```

I want to start this function when I press the "1" key. How do I do this

Comment: I can't figure out the onkeydown code. I would love to use that.

Comment: The answer is all over the place.
Check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7555375/465738

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 41) {
      // do a function
   }
}
```

instead of onkeypress you can look at onkeydown / onkeyup

List of char codes: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: do I need anything in the HTML

Comment: No, just this code inside a script tag or an external js included

Comment: ok thanks. will this code work if I change it to onkeydown?

Comment: Yeah, just the time where the code is executed changes ... keypress is when the key was pressed and then released, keydown when the key is pressed

Comment: so I put my code from above inside the if?

Comment: no, you put the code at the beggining of your code for example ...

Comment: can you please post it as a new answer. i cant see the whole comment

Comment: I made the '...' myself.

Comment: where you have window.onkeypress=function(event) do i replace function with my function name

Comment: @muzzledog > you need to call addone() inside the if, where TobSpr put the comment `// do a function`

Comment: currently it is not working