# activate this function with onkeypress 1

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

```
 function addone()

 {

 document.getElementById("subtract").disabled=false;
x += 1;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Doshi has said OK " + x + " times."
 if(x == 1 ){
document.getElementById("resetall").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("reset").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Doshi has said OK " + x + " time."
 }
    if(x == 0){
document.getElementById("resetall").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("reset").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Doshi has not said OK " 
}

  }
```

how do i activate this function with onkeydown. I want to use the "1" key. I can activate it with any key at the moment. I want it to be the 1 key

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activate a Javascript function with a keypress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735197/activate-a-javascript-function-with-a-keypress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.which === 49 || e.keyCode === 49) {  // '1'.charCodeAt(0)
        addone();
    }

    return true; // allow normal keyboard output
};
```

Comment: Try an `alert` or a `console.log` in place of the call to `addOne` for debugging purposes.  It is possible addOne is not defined in the scope of the event listener

Comment: Just realized there's a browser-incompatibility for getting the event's key code.  Updated answer.

Comment: Yes, both which and keyCode are present in KeyboardEvent.

Comment: window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.which == 49 || e.keyCode == 49) {  
        addone();
    }

    return true; 
};
this works in chrome but not ie9

Comment: Make sure `addone` is spelled correctly because JS is case sensitive.  I used `addOne` but I just realized your method is actually called `addone`.  Your issue may be elsewhere.

Comment: It works fine in chrome. But in Ie9 id doesn't. I use Ie9 and not chrome becasue my css is not compatible with my version of chrome.

Comment: You have to understand I'm flying blind here.  It works just fine for me in IE9.  Perhaps post as a separate question and include your HTML/CSS.  If your CSS isn't working cross-browser then there may be a larger issue.

Comment: if you want you want I can send you all my files on it.